# VueJS/AdonisJs image upload and usage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, adonis.js

I'm building a webapp that needs to display some images, the frontend is build with VueJS and the backend is build with AdonisJS.

I'm currently having a problem that I'm uploading images from my frontend to my backend. AdonisJS generates a storage path that is local. As example, I upload from my frontend in this form:

[Input form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRX6m.png)

That uses this code on the VueJS side:

```
let formData = new FormData();
      let imagefile = document.querySelector('#file');
      formData.append("image", imagefile.files[0]);
      axios.post('/users/' + this.user.id + "/image", formData, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'image/*'
          }
      })
```

And on the AdonisJS side:

```
* updateProfilePicture(request, response) {
    const image = request.file('image', { 
        maxSize: '20mb',
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg']
    }) 

    const userId = request.param('id'); 
    const user = yield User.findOrFail(userId)

    const fileName = `${new Date().getTime()}.${image.extension()}` 
    yield image.move(Helpers.storagePath(), fileName) 

    if (!image.moved()) {
        response.badRequest(image.errors())
        return
    }
    user.profilepicture = image.uploadPath() 

    yield user.save();
    response.ok(user);
}
```

Which is working at the moment, but that generates a path that is used by AdonisJS:

```
ProjectFolder/backend/storage/1500586654324.jpg
```

VueJS is located in:

```
ProjectFolder/frontend/*
```

How can I use my uploaded images in the frontend? Is there some way that these frameworks can be coupled?

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple way to get this image accessible via the browser.

1. You create a `route` within Adonis to handle a "media" route (like `~/media/1500586654324.jpg`). This route will take the image ID and send the correspondant image inside your `storage` folder.
2. You don't upload your image to your `storage` folder and instead put them directly into the `public` folder of your application that means you can access the image directly via its URL.

I prefer using the first option since my `public` directory is 100% generated via script.